# Intelligent spheres and abduction

Tags: story-identification, alien-abduction

I am trying to remember the title of a book I read as a preteen. It was about a boy, I believe named Max, but could be wrong. He was about to die in a car accident, but was taken at the last second. The abductors were intelligent spheres, and saved people and brought them to live in domes that simulated earth, with one detail being that they reproduced rain but not thunder and lightning because it scared the elderly people they saved. Some of these details may be sketchy but I would love to know the book again...

Comment: Do you have any idea when it might have been written? E.g when did you read it?

Comment: I read it in the early 90's, probably 90-91 or so.....

Answer (score 1):

This is probably Franch Asch's *[Journey to Terezor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1441402.Journey_to_Terezor)*, with the protagonist's name being "Matt" rather than "Max":

[image: Book cover - *Journey to Terezor*]

> Matt can hardly believe it. One minute, he and his parents are scrambling to safety during a flash flood in Ohio. The next minute, two kids his age are telling him that he's the latest Earthling to be imprisoned by alien robots on an isolated planet. Matt and his friends must make a desperate bid for freedom that takes them halfway across the galaxy.

This was submitted as an answer to [Book about a kid who gets pulled out of his reality right as a car accident happens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173304/book-about-a-kid-who-gets-pulled-out-of-his-reality-right-as-a-car-accident-happ), and this question was mentioned among possibly related questions, so I looked up references that matched up with this question.

Comment: possibly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-young-adult-sf-book-is-about-a-boy-saved-by-aliens-and-domed-colonies