# Book about a kid who gets pulled out of his reality right as a car accident happens

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I have been trying to find this book for years to share with my kids, it would have been from the 90s. It was young adult sci-fi. The cover had a boy falling and a silver orb floating next to him.

The story is about a kid who gets pulled out of his reality right as a car accident happens, and I believe that they replaced him or his body with a clone, Millennium style. The world he is pulled into is covered by a dome, and run by silver orbs. The weather is controlled and it only rains on certain days, at the same time, with no thunder or lightning because it scares to kids and old folks.

The people are forbidden from leaving the dome, so of course the boy and a friend he makes do just that and adventure ensues. I can't remember the end of the book.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I'd look at titles by Monica Hughes. She was quite a prolific writer of YA novels from the 1970's up to the 2000's. Aspects of what you describe, the domed city, rain allowed on certain days, people forbidden from leaving the dome, sound superficially like her novel The Tomorrow City. The cover, cover the car accident and the silver orbs do not match but I wonder if you are conflating two of her works? There is a list of her titles on wikipedia (link below). Have a look and see if anything rings bells. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Hughes

Answer (score 3):

*[Journey to Terezor](http://frankasch.com/journey-to-terezor/2013/10/)* by Frank Asch

[image: Book cover - *Journey to Terezor*]

> Matt Hilton is kidnapped and taken to a galactic “reserve” for endangered species. There he encounters Ryan Morrison, a young but determined scientist, and Sara Hollings, who more than anything yearns to see Earth. Together they begin a perilous quest for freedom. Matt is forced to masquerade as an alien from the unique realm of Galator, while Ryan and Sara undergo the rigors of “displacement”, a process that shrinks them into tiny black holes. As they journey, their goal becomes one of mere survival until they realize the ultimate challenge that awaits them in the planetary system of Terezor.

Comment: If you could provide some more details that would be immensely helpful. Adding in snippets of text that match up to your description, or even just a link. Remember in 48 hours you can hit that green checkmark and confirm the answer for all time. It would be incredibly useful for us if you hit that checkmark in 48 hours time!

Comment: Since the question dates from 2017, he can do it immediately.

Comment: And this will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-young-adult-sf-book-is-about-a-boy-saved-by-aliens-and-domed-colonies/2392#2392

Comment: We would still like you to formally accept this one. Acceptance by comment is allowable for the dupe, but we prefer to the answer to actually be marked as answered.