# Boy gets transported to a planet where people can transform into different species

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, artificial-intelligence

When I was a kid I read a book about a boy who gets transported to a different planet.

The people are put in different domes, with different creatures.  Main character either escapes to another dome or crashes in it. I can’t remember which.  An old shaman type person takes him in and "trains" him in their ways.  On occasion one of the "people" is chosen to eat a special fruit and some dirt, after which they genetically transform into another creature.

Main character later eats one of the fruits and transforms into the original species of the planet.  That species has been extinct for a long time but robots are maintaining a preservative program for other species.  The kid escapes back to Earth by convincing the robots that he really *is* one of the indigenous species and shuts the robots down. Afterwards he returns to human form by eating another fruit and some dirt from Earth.

Comment: When were you a kid?

Comment: Late 80’s early 90’s. Read it at the same time as I read ‘Space trap’ by Monica Hughes.

Comment: @invisible you might want to take a look at [the policy on story I’d dupes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/58193). If the answer is the same and accepted they should be dupe closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Journey to Terezor* by Frank Asch

It was the answer to [the "What young adult SF book is about a boy saved by aliens and domed colonies?" question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-young-adult-sf-book-is-about-a-boy-saved-by-aliens-and-domed-colonies).

> Matt and his parents are rescued from a flood by alien robots who have
>   set up colonies of intelligent beings from various worlds on Planet
>   S-15. Matt joins two other children, Sarah and Ryan, in an attempt to
>   reprogram a robot to get them back to Earth. Sarah and Ryan are
>   caught, but Matt escapes to another colony and lives with the alien
>   Dar for a while. Cyber, the robot, returns for him; they rescue Sarah
>   and Ryan and set out for Terezor, the original planet of the robots.
>   There, Matt changes his body to that of a (now extinct) Terezor and
>   reprograms the master computer.

Comment: YES! This sounds so right. Thank you!